# Validate urls using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, validation, url, python-requests

i want to do some basic url validation,and if url is invalid,request should not be proceed unless user have entered a valid one.
**Update**: To be more clear I do not want the browser to be opened and image counter scipt to be runed unless the entered Url is valid.

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

user_url = input('Please enter a valid url:')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/m/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get(user_url)
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

time.sleep(8)

imagecounter = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('img')

print('Number of HTML image tags:')
print(len(imagecounter))
```

Could you please modify the code and explain what is happening?
 I have tried with some libraries, but i think because of my poor coding skills there was no luck.

Comment: You need to define what is "valid" and what is "invalid"

Comment: I would suggest to first validate the syntax with pythons `urlparse`, then do the `sleep(8)`, then validate the url response code, then find elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use requests to get the HTTP status code

```py
    import requests
    import time 
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    user_url = input('Please enter a valid url:')

    # send a get request to the page, and if the status code is not OK
    # ask for a different url
    def valid_url(url):
        try:
            req = requests.get(url)
            while req.status_code != requests.codes['ok']:
                  return valid_url(input('Please enter a valid url:'))
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f'Something went wrong: {ex}')
            print('Try again!')
            return valid_url(input('Please enter a valid url:'))


        return url

    url = valid_url(user_url)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url) # funtion is called here
    HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

    time.sleep(8)

    imagecounter = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('img')

    print('Number of HTML image tags:')
    print(len(imagecounter))
```

Comment: I am getting error if I input  something like: "something.com".

requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'something.com': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://something.com?

Comment: If i input invalid URL like https:// stackkkkkkkkkkoverflow.com  I get error:

 Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: In that case, you can add a try-except. I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit,
Unfortunately I am still getting errors:
If I enter "sometext" script prompts me to input again,but it chrashes if i put valid url after it.

Comment: And if i 1st put invalid url like https:// stackover888888flow.com/ it promts to input the valid url again, but after that if valid url is entered the script does not return all the image tags.

Comment: @ArashIzmirov Could you please tell what error occurs?  I do not have an error. Also, Please note it is now a funtion, which is called on this line: driver.get(valid_url(user_url)). I added some comments for clarity

Comment: Regarding the image tags. Does this happen without this block? You might consider asking a separate question.

Comment: Regarding the image tags - no it does not happen without the block.

Comment: To be more clear I do not want the browser to be opened and image counter scipt to be runed unless the entered Url is valid.

Comment: @ArashIzmirov  Edited the answer to fix the error. The browser opens when you call webdriver.Chrome(), which happens before validation. I edited the validation to happen first. Please tell if any other errors still occure

Answer (score 0):

To validate a user provided url before proceeding you can use *Python's* [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests) module to check the request status andyou can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import requests

  while True:
      user_url = str(input("Please enter a valid url:"))
      req = requests.get(user_url)
      if req.status_code != requests.codes['ok']:
          print("Not a valid url, please try again...")
          continue
      else:
          break
  print("URL was a valid one... Continuing...")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get(user_url)
  # perform your rest of the tasks
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Please enter a valid url:https://www.goodday.com
  Not a valid url, please try again...
  Please enter a valid url:https://www.goodday.com
  Not a valid url, please try again...
  Please enter a valid url:https://www.goodday.com
  Not a valid url, please try again...
  Please enter a valid url:https://www.google.com
  URL was a valid one... Continuing...

  DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54638/devtools/browser/975e0993-166a-4144-a05f-dcfb1d9b29a2
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to pass validated user input with in an input field of a webpage using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812328/how-to-pass-validated-user-input-with-in-an-input-field-of-a-webpage-using-selen/59815377#59815377)
- [Start from the beginning using while loop on connection times out using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811236/start-from-the-beginning-using-while-loop-on-connection-times-out-using-selenium/59814423#59814423)

Comment: Thank you, but, unfortunately it does not work if I enter something like: ''sometext345''

Comment: @ArashIzmirov You are asking the user to provide a valid [url](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_4.2.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.internet.doc/topics/dfhtl_uricomp.html) and an **url** is normally made up of three or four components e.g. a) A scheme.b) A host c) A path d) A query string. The input you are testing i.e. **sometext345** isn't an url but a string. Seethe example I have used.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and explaining, you have helped a lot.